# Combining multiple Counts

Tags: sql, join, count

I'm Trying to combine this set of `queries`.
I have done the search but my `queries` has some `joins` , it's getting complicated, can somebody help?

```
select count(DISTINCT p.products_id) as count  from (products p)
                            join (products_to_categories p2c)
                              on (p.products_id = p2c.products_id)
                            left join (specials s)
                              on (p.products_id = s.products_id)
                            left join (products_attributes pa)
                              on (p.products_id = pa.products_id)
                            left join (products_options_values pv)
                              on (pa.options_values_id = pv.products_options_values_id)
                            left join (products_stock ps)
                              on (p.products_id=ps.products_id and pv.products_options_values_id = ps.products_options_values_id2)        
                                                 INNER JOIN products_specifications ps10 ON p.products_id = ps10.products_id  INNER JOIN products_specifications ps17 ON p.products_id = ps17.products_id  where p.products_status = '1' and ps.products_stock_quantity>0   and p2c.categories_id in (72,1,23,47,48,49,74,24,33,34,35,77,25,46,45,44,40,41,42,43,76,78,83,50,52,81,79,2,54,60,82,53,57,58,55,61,62,63,75,56,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,84,80)  AND ps10.specification in ('Meisje') AND ps10.specifications_id = '10'
                      AND ps10.language_id = '1'
                       and products_options_values_name in ( 80,"18M/80cm","8-12 mnd","9m","12m","9-12m","9M","12M" )  AND ps17.specification in ('Overhemd', 'Polo') AND ps17.specifications_id = '17'
                      AND ps17.language_id = '1'
```

---

```
select count(DISTINCT p.products_id) as count  from (products p)
                            join (products_to_categories p2c)
                              on (p.products_id = p2c.products_id)
                            left join (specials s)
                              on (p.products_id = s.products_id)
                            left join (products_attributes pa)
                              on (p.products_id = pa.products_id)
                            left join (products_options_values pv)
                              on (pa.options_values_id = pv.products_options_values_id)
                            left join (products_stock ps)
                              on (p.products_id=ps.products_id and pv.products_options_values_id = ps.products_options_values_id2)        
                                                 INNER JOIN products_specifications ps10 ON p.products_id = ps10.products_id  INNER JOIN products_specifications ps17 ON p.products_id = ps17.products_id  where p.products_status = '1' and ps.products_stock_quantity>0   and p2c.categories_id in (72,1,23,47,48,49,74,24,33,34,35,77,25,46,45,44,40,41,42,43,76,78,83,50,52,81,79,2,54,60,82,53,57,58,55,61,62,63,75,56,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,84,80)  AND ps10.specification in ('Jongen') AND ps10.specifications_id = '10'
                      AND ps10.language_id = '1'
                       and products_options_values_name in ( 80,"18M/80cm","8-12 mnd","9m","12m","9-12m","9M","12M" )  AND ps17.specification in ('Overhemd', 'Polo') AND ps17.specifications_id = '17'
                      AND ps17.language_id = '1'
```

---

```
select count(DISTINCT p.products_id) as count  from (products p)
                            join (products_to_categories p2c)
                              on (p.products_id = p2c.products_id)
                            left join (specials s)
                              on (p.products_id = s.products_id)
                            left join (products_attributes pa)
                              on (p.products_id = pa.products_id)
                            left join (products_options_values pv)
                              on (pa.options_values_id = pv.products_options_values_id)
                            left join (products_stock ps)
                              on (p.products_id=ps.products_id and pv.products_options_values_id = ps.products_options_values_id2)        
                                                 INNER JOIN products_specifications ps10 ON p.products_id = ps10.products_id  INNER JOIN products_specifications ps17 ON p.products_id = ps17.products_id  where p.products_status = '1' and ps.products_stock_quantity>0   and p2c.categories_id in (72,1,23,47,48,49,74,24,33,34,35,77,25,46,45,44,40,41,42,43,76,78,83,50,52,81,79,2,54,60,82,53,57,58,55,61,62,63,75,56,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,84,80)  AND ps10.specification in ('Unisex') AND ps10.specifications_id = '10'
                      AND ps10.language_id = '1'
                       and products_options_values_name in ( 80,"18M/80cm","8-12 mnd","9m","12m","9-12m","9M","12M" )  AND ps17.specification in ('Overhemd', 'Polo') AND ps17.specifications_id = '17'
                      AND ps17.language_id = '1'
```

Comment: What is different in these queries? Also please paste you expected output.

Comment: it's mysql, the differene is in ps10.specification in ('Meisje'),ps10.specification in ('Jongen'),ps10.specification in ('Unisex')

Comment: expected output is  
count  
1  
10  
1  
  
sometime it needs to join 20 counts so union is not an option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with this and seems to work

The output is

```
count1   count2   count3
------------------------
  10        0        2
```

@john bingham "your queries contain a bit of redundancy"

Can you help me make this query a bit less redundancy?

```
select 
    count(DISTINCT if(ps10.specification in ('Meisje'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count1,
    count(DISTINCT if(ps10.specification in ('Jongen'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count2,
    count(DISTINCT if(ps10.specification in ('Unisex'),p.products_id,NULL)) as count3
from 
    (products p)
join 
    (products_to_categories p2c) on (p.products_id = p2c.products_id)
left join 
    (specials s) on (p.products_id = s.products_id)
left join 
    (products_attributes pa) on (p.products_id = pa.products_id)
left join 
    (products_options_values pv) on (pa.options_values_id = pv.products_options_values_id)
left join 
    (products_stock ps) on (p.products_id = ps.products_id 
                        and pv.products_options_values_id = ps.products_options_values_id2)       
inner join
    products_specifications ps10 ON p.products_id = ps10.products_id  
where 
    p.products_status = '1' 
    and ps.products_stock_quantity > 0   
    and p2c.categories_id in (72,1,23,47,48,49,74,24,33,34,35,77,25,46,45,44,40,41,42,43,76,78,83,50,52,81,79,2,54,60,82,53,57,58,55,61,62,63,75,56,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,84,80)  
    and ps10.specifications_id = '10'
    and ps10.language_id = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, your queries contain a bit of redundancy because they join tables which are unused in both the select and where clauses. I've removed these in my solution below. I've also reorganised the remaining joins to put all mandatory joins before any optional ones.

```
select ps10.specification, count(DISTINCT p.products_id) as [count]
from products p
  join products_to_categories p2c on p.products_id = p2c.products_id
  join products_specifications ps10 ON p.products_id = ps10.products_id  
  join products_specifications ps17 ON p.products_id = ps17.products_id  
  left join products_stock ps on p.products_id=ps.products_id and pv.products_options_values_id = ps.products_options_values_id2
where p.products_status = '1' and ps.products_stock_quantity > 0 
  and p2c.categories_id in (72,1,23,47,48,49,74,24,33,34,35,77,25,46,45,44,40,41,42,43,76,78,83,50,52,81,79,2,54,60,82,53,57,58,55,61,62,63,75,56,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,84,80)
  and ps10.specification in ('Meisje', 'Jongen', 'Unisex') 
  and ps10.specifications_id = '10'
  and ps10.language_id = '1'
  and products_options_values_name in ( 80,"18M/80cm","8-12 mnd","9m","12m","9-12m","9M","12M")
  and ps17.specification in ('Overhemd', 'Polo') 
  and ps17.specifications_id = '17'
  and ps17.language_id = '1' 
GROUP BY ps10.specification
ORDER BY ps10.specification
```

This will produce the following output:

```
specification | count
Jongen          93
Maisje          245
Unisex          36
```

(well the numbers might be a bit bogus)

Hope this helps

Comment: I get this error  #1054 - Unknown column 'products_options_values_name' in 'where clause'